# Add documents to ElasticSearch index through javascript loop does not work

Tags: javascript, loops, elasticsearch

I retrieved a lot of rows from my PostgreSQL database (stored in `result.rows`) and I want to add them into my **ElasticSearch** index.

Add only one document works fine:

```
var r = result.rows[0];
esClient.index({
  index: 'families',
  type: 'families',
  id: r.family_accession,
  body: {
      'family_accession'  : r.family_accession,
      'count_seq'         : r.count_seq,
      'count_taxon'       : r.count_taxon
  }
}, function (error, response) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

But when I try to call it into a loop, it does not work at all:

```
result.rows.forEach(function (r) {
  esClient.index({
    index: 'families',
    type: 'families',
    id: r.family_accession,
    body: {
        'family_accession'  : r.family_accession,
        'count_seq'         : r.count_seq,
        'count_taxon'       : r.count_taxon
    }
  }, function (error, response) {
    console.log(error);
  });
});
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: are you sure result.rows is a collection ? Could you provide a sample json ?

Comment: @Val There is no error at all. The loop iterates well (I can print `r`) but `error` and `response` are never printed...

Comment: Note that there is no `console.log(response)` in your code.

Comment: @juliendangers `result.rows` is an array of objects: [ { 'family_accession': 'foo', 'count_seq': '10', 'count_taxon': '11' }, { 'family_accession': 'bar', 'count_seq': '5', 'count_taxon': '50' }, ...]. The problem does not come from this because I can iterate on it and use one row works.

Comment: @Val Sure, I simplified for the post. A `console.log('#');` in the callback function is never triggerred either

Comment: @juliendangers yes, even `[ result.rows[0] ].forEach(function(r) { ... });` works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're calling an asynchronous piece of code within a loop, the context that was present when the `esClient.index()` function was called is not present anymore by the time your callback executes.

You need to enclose it in a closure to keep the execution context around.

```
result.rows.forEach(function (r) {
  (function( row ) {
    esClient.index({
      index: 'families',
      type: 'families',
      id: row.family_accession,
      body: {
          'family_accession'  : row.family_accession,
          'count_seq'         : row.count_seq,
          'count_taxon'       : row.count_taxon
      }
    }, function (error, response) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  })( r );
});
```

Comment: It's working! I though it wasn't because the loop needs to finish entirely to see the index modifications in ElasticSearch.

Comment: I have a related problem. This code works but not for hundred of thousands rows. How can I fill my index using millions of rows ?

Comment: If you're trying to insert hundreds of thousands of documents, I suggest you should try using the [bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-bulk) instead. But that should be another question, so that this one remains uncluttered.